# RouterModule - Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement routing in Angular but getting error
`Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined`
my app.routes.ts file is

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../../components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../../components/signup/signup.component';
import { ResourcesComponent } from '../../components/resources/resources.component';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
const routes: Routes=[
    {path:'',component:MyApp},
    {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
    {path:'signup', component:SignupComponent},
    {path:'resources',component:ResourcesComponent},
];
export const routing=RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

app.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../../components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../../components/signup/signup.component';
import { ResourcesComponent } from '../../components/resources/resources.component'; 
import { NavbarComponent } from '../../components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    declarations:[
        MyApp,
        LoginComponent,
        SignupComponent,
        ResourcesComponent,
        NavbarComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [MyApp],
    imports:[BrowserModule,RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    bootstrap: [MyApp]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

but gets error for RouterModule and routes i.e. @angular/router/index has no exported member 'RouterModule' and 'Routes'

Comment: are you sure that the error is related to the app.routes.ts file? Is MyApp your main component? if that is the case, you should not use it inside of your routes

Comment: You have `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` twice there, both in routes file and in module file. Decide to use either ;)

Comment: That's not the problem.though i have removed from routes file

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule

You should use `RouterModule` inside `NgModule`. So your file should export `routes` instead `routing`:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../../components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../../components/signup/signup.component';
import { ResourcesComponent } from '../../components/resources/resources.component';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
export const routes: Routes=[
    {path:'',component:MyApp},
    {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
    {path:'signup', component:SignupComponent},
    {path:'resources',component:ResourcesComponent},
];
```

and then in module file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)]
})
class MyNgModule {}
```

Comment: Thats not true as far as I know, the forRoot method of the RouterModule can be called outside of a module. Its static and returns a new module

Comment: I have implemented the way i you proposed but the same error persists.

Comment: And have a typescript error that `@angular/router/index has no exported member RouterModule, Routes`

Comment: Which version of angular do you have installed? 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which version of angular using . I think you are using (following) some deprecated way to route . 
You can use the routes as @Maciej Soabala has shown above . 
If you want to export the routes as a separate module you can follow this also

https://angular.io/guide/router#refactor-the-routing-configuration-into-a-routing-module

then you code will look like

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from '../../components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../../components/signup/signup.component';
import { ResourcesComponent } from '../../components/resources/resources.component';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
const routes: Routes=[
    {path:'',component:MyApp},
    {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
    {path:'signup', component:SignupComponent},
    {path:'resources',component:ResourcesComponent},
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class routing{}
```

then you can import routing as you want in other modules and use it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **SystemJS** version **0.20** or later to load your module, use the following setting:

`System.config({
    meta: {
        "./*": {
        "esModule": true
        }
    }
<more settings>
});`